# kotlin: After inserting data list does not refresh with new data sometimes

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin

I am running tthe following code:

```
        doAsync{
            val result = URL("https://www.***.com/ajax/app/send.php?email="+email+"&email_own="+email_own+"&mes="+editTextTextMultiLine.getText().toString()).readText()
            uiThread {
                 toast(result)
               }
        }
```

Now i fetch the data and my recycleview does not refresh with the new data (sometimes it does but not always):

```
        doAsync{
            val result = URL("https://www.***.com/ajax/app/get_m_profile3.php?email="+email+"&email_zelf="+email_own).readText()
            uiThread {
               // toast(result)
                val root = JSONObject(result)
                val array: JSONArray = root.getJSONArray("data")
                val heroes = array?.let { arrayOfNulls<String>(it.length()) }
                val foto = array?.let { arrayOfNulls<String>(it.length()) }
                val email2 = array?.let { arrayOfNulls<String>(it.length()) }
                val mes = array?.let { arrayOfNulls<String>(it.length()) }
                for (i in 0 until array.length()) {
                    val `object` = array.getJSONObject(i)
                    heroes?.set(i, `object`.getString("name"))
                    foto?.set(i, `object`.getString("photo"))
                    mes?.set(i, `object`.getString("mes"))
                    email2?.set(i, `object`.getString("email"))
                }
                rv!!.adapter = MyAdapterMessagesProfile(
                    applicationContext,
                    heroes,
                    foto,
                    email2,
                    mes
                )
                rv!!.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You shouldn't keep initialize your `adapter`. Just create a function inside your adapter to update these value. It maybe affected because of the duplicated initialization.

Comment: How can i do this can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you should create another function to update the value.

Adapter

```
class MyAdapterMessagesProfile(
   private val context: Context,
   private val heroes: Array<String>, 
   private val foto: Array<String>,
   private val email2: Array<String>, 
   private val mes: Array<String>
): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

   internal fun setData(heroes: Array<String>, foto: Array<String>, email2: Array<String>, mes: Array<String>) {
      // update all the value inside adapter
      this.heroes = heroes
      this.foto = foto
      this.email2 = email2 
      this.mes = mes

      // IMPORTANT
      notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
}
```

View

```
// initialized this in onCreate() or onViewCreated()
override fun onCreate() {
    // avoid using !! to prevent NPE
    rv?.adapter = MyAdapterMessagesProfile(
                    applicationContext,
                    heroes,
                    foto,
                    email2,
                    mes
                ) 
}
 

 doAsync{
            val result = URL("https://www.***.com/ajax/app/get_m_profile3.php?email="+email+"&email_zelf="+email_own).readText()
            uiThread {
               // toast(result)
                val root = JSONObject(result)
                val array: JSONArray = root.getJSONArray("data")
                val heroes = array?.let { arrayOfNulls<String>(it.length()) }
                val foto = array?.let { arrayOfNulls<String>(it.length()) }
                val email2 = array?.let { arrayOfNulls<String>(it.length()) }
                val mes = array?.let { arrayOfNulls<String>(it.length()) }
                for (i in 0 until array.length()) {
                    val `object` = array.getJSONObject(i)
                    heroes?.set(i, `object`.getString("name"))
                    foto?.set(i, `object`.getString("photo"))
                    mes?.set(i, `object`.getString("mes"))
                    email2?.set(i, `object`.getString("email"))
                }
                // update your value
                rv?.adapter.setData(heroes, foto, emails2, mes) 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I now have this adapter:


adapter = RecyclerViewAdapterMessageProfile(this, items, items2, items3, items4)

So how do i created a function inside this adapter to refresh my recycleview? 
When I create a function like above example I can't invoke the function from my activity...

Comment: There is a `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter's setData, it will update the entire recyclerview when you called it